# Difference between the Gnosis multisig and Gnosis safe?

Tags: multisignature, gnosis

What differentiate them? I am looing for a confirmation that the Gnosis safe is the latest and recommended wallet from Gnosis for multisignature.

Web version for both:

- Multisig: https://wallet.gnosis.pm/#/wallets
- Safe: https://gnosis-safe.io/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gnosis Safe is the latest release of the Gnosis Multisig Wallets. The Gnosis Safe Multisig wallet can be deployed either as a standalone contract, or (preferably) as a cheaper proxy contract that points to a known, trusted, legitimate, implementation contract of the Gnosis Safe Multisig wallet.  Gnosis provides a ProxyFactory contract that can be used to easily deploy Proxy contracts in front of the Gnosis Safe Multisig implementation. Please refer to the following diagram to understand the interaction between the deployer and the Gnosis Safe.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The wallet.gnosis.pm is the version 1.0. Safe is the version 2.0 It is highly recommended to use Safe unless you have want to dive in to the world of pain.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Safe is just the upgraded version of Gnosis multisig.